# Django channels - disconnect WebSocket from server side when token expires or gets invalid

Tags: django, websocket, jwt, django-channels

I searched about this topic, specifically for Django, but i did not find any applicable solution.

Namely, when i use a JWT as a query parameter to authenticate the user while opening a socket connection, the problem i'm thinking of is that the connection can be open for a long time which can exceed the validity of the token. The token can expire or even get invalid if some data changes.

If someone steals the token which is expired, he can't really do anything with it because he cannot establish a new socket connection, so i assume this is not a big deal (maybe i'm wrong).

The validity of the token on the data side is a bit different. If i used a data part to define the channel name, and then exactly that information changes, the old socket connection will receive the old data even when it should not.
For example, if i used users company name for the channel name, and then the admin changes users company, while the old socket connection is still open, the user will still receive data from the old company until the old connection is disconnected and new one established.

So i would need somehow to close the connection from the server-side if that's possible, or stop sending the data to that specific user, and i'm not sure how to do that.

Any kind of advice on handling this concerns is appreciated.